# Vertical align for overflow:hidden inline block with different lineheight

Tags: css

Having difficulties with vertical align of inline element with overflow: hidden and differrent line height. Basically this is problem:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    .mybutton {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 36px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;

        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }

    span {
        font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .mybutton span {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 4px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .overflow-ellipsis {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li style="height: 36px">
        <span>
            <button class="mybutton">
                <span class="overflow-ellipsis">11111111111111111111111111111</span>
            </button>
            <span>111</span>
        </span>
        <span>111</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And concrete problems are:

1. This markup is well aligned in Chrome, however in IE 11 first element is a bit lower than second one.
2. Changing Font to Arial will make it bad aligned in Chrome also.

Any idea how to fix this is welcome.

Note: different line height, overflow: hidden and display: inline-block (on button and contained span) is a MUST

Comment: .mybutton Change display: inline-block to display: inline-flex;

Comment: @zubairkhanzada this does not change anything in Chrome/IE for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative margin on `.overflow-ellipsis` solves the problem:

```
.overflow-ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Preview it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chiragbhansali/tt606a56/7/)